# Transferring content of block devices

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, block-device, disk-image

For the purpose of backups, I'd like to transfer (several) whole disk partitions over an ssh link. The source is a block special device and the target should be a regular file. Common tools seem ill-suited for this, though:

- `scp` will complain `not a regular file`
- `tar` will try to recreate device inodes on the target side
- `rsync` says `skipping non-regular file`

My best bet currently is `nc` over a port forwarding, or one `cat` invocation on the remote side per partition, which means one password entry per partition unless one sets up public keys. Is there a more elegant solution?

Environment would be any reasonable Linux live system. Currently I happen to have a Debian wheezy lying around, but it should not be *too* specific to that.

Comment: Please provide the OS, distribution and version you are working with.  Althought I might have an alternative, I'd like to be sure that it applicable to your specific case.

Comment: @mdpc: Linux, e.g. Debian wheezy. Updated my question to include that information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could pipe through SSH. Example using `dd`:

```
dd bs=1M if=/dev/disk | ssh -C target dd bs=1M of=disk.img
```

If the network connection breaks during transfer, you can resume if you know how much was copied. For example if you're sure at least `1000MiB` were transferred already (check the file size of `disk.img`):

```
dd bs=1M skip=1000 if=/dev/disk | ssh -C target dd bs=1M seek=1000 of=disk.img
```

`dd` is just an example, it works just as well with other commands, as long as they work with pipes.

Comment: Why would you use `dd`? To slow things down?

Comment: I **love** `dd`. It works great, and I don't have any complaints about its performance. YMMV.

Comment: What advantage does it bring compared to the simpler, less error-prone `</dev/disk ssh -C target 'cat >disk.img'`, that would compensate the additional risk of error (`if` typoed as `of` is a biggie)?

Comment: It lets you resume, for one thing. But we're arguing opinions here. It's pointless. You don't like `dd`, you use something else. It's that simple. As for typos, you can just as well confuse `<` and `>` and in many cases it's just as catastrophic.

Comment: If you have a fast connection between the machines, the `-C` option for `ssh` will likely slow down your transfer.

Answer (score 5):

I'd install the buffer program (if it is not already there in your distribution) if you are trying to transfer via an ethernet link.  It is like dd but FAR better and faster.  Basically it is programmed to do concurrent reads and writes using a shared memory buffer.  I used to use this for tape dumps and it saved about 10% transfer time.  The command line would be:

```
  buffer -i /dev/disk -m 100m | ssh -C target buffer -o disk.image -m 100m
```

There are more options available default blocksize is 10K.  The above allocates 100MBytes of shared memory, you might have to adjust either this parameter or your configuration to allow this.

WARNING: Transmission of an ACTIVE partition in this manner will be problematic.  So make sure that the partition to be transmitted is NOT mounted.

Comment: how to resume if network connection breaks during transfer?

Comment: If you have a fast connection between the machines, the `-C` option for `ssh` will likely slow down your transfer.

Comment: Source: http://www.hello-penguin.com/software.htm  Last updated in Jan 2000.